# Ether not transferring

Tags: mist, ether

When I send ether from one of my accounts to the other a transaction is sent but after the confirmations there is still no ether transferred. I didn't get any obvious error messages

Comment: Did you check the blockNo by `eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)` and check if block number is not null to be sure that your transaction is mined?

Comment: @prashant-prabhakar-singh I just checked and it wasnt null

Comment: Have you provided enough gas?

Comment: @Susmit I didnt change the gas number so maybe not im trying with increased gas at the moment

Comment: @Susmit I tried with increased gas and it still didnt work

Comment: Is you blockchain up to date (synchronized)?

Comment: I don't know what the problem was but I restarted the chain from block 0 and haven't had the problem since

Answer (score 1):

Simply Sending ethers will not get transferred. It needs to be mined.

Please check whether you have started the miner.

If in case your miner is running validate **eth.hashrate** and **eth.blockNumber** in geth console. It should not be zero. If it comes zero then your miner is not having the computational power. To start mining minimum we need 4GB RAM.

Please check **eth.pendingTransactions**. If the transaction still in pending status, then it was not get mined.

If there is no transaction pending then you will get empty array like below.

```
> eth.pendingTransactions
[]
>
```

If your connecting and running in *testnet*, obviously it will take some time.

Comment: As per Joe, the blockNumber is not null, so definitely the transaction is mined and included in a block.

Answer (score 0):

Since the blockNumber is not null, so your transaction is mined successfully. The only reason I could think of is your blockChain is not in sycn. 
Suppose your transaction is included in blockNumber `xxxx` (you can check blockNumber of your transaction by `eth.getTransactionReceipt("transactionHash")`, then your account will not show updated balance until your blockchain downloads the `xxxx` blocks. 
So wait until your node is fully synced. Your ethers will definitely appear after your node downloads the block in which your transaction is included.

`eth.getTransactionReceipt("transactionHash")` will return something like below.

```
> eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x6a66d2dbc1610e20405828fdbfbf7b028ec3ce5d20e3800267e0f99b70be1426")
{
  blockHash: "0x414049a38df383bfa0e71ad1b1618ff8d08b45ce16064c27aed205d905048e36",
  blockNumber: 10436,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 42000,
  from: "0x2de46430bc377ad5a1e4c2cdfea7baa1a6baf092",
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: "0xa6521114fe5c68ad252b163d7eac7415cd89c6259d8cdee47f681f14cefad6f0",
  to: "0xf74c6516c4f7c87c663f3aefce67d815fb1bf047",
  transactionHash: "0x6a66d2dbc1610e20405828fdbfbf7b028ec3ce5d20e3800267e0f99b70be1426",
  transactionIndex: 1
}
```